# Using SharePoint subsites and audience to target content... how?

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, sharepoint-2007

I would like to show different tabs in the top navigation of a SharePoint site depending on what 'Audience' the user is in. I can do this fine for pages but for subsites I cannot find an option. Googling reveals a work around, hiding the subsite and adding a link to the subsite URL.

There has to be a better way than this!

Comment: I don´t think you can add audiencetargetting to the SPWeb object, thus you have to go with a heading or link. The SPWeb object is dependent on permissions, not audiences.

Comment: I am cry! Make your comment an answer and you will earn points and we can see if people agree with you! Here's hoping there is a work around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is by actually using Usergroups in Sharepoint. Audiences are nothing more than a form of display:none; like in CSS. If you know the URL, you still can get access. SPWeb knows only about allowing security objects (SPUSer / SPGroup) access to it...